# Not enough reputation - wanting to answer/comment

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges

I've seen a few questions I'd like to comment on or give a different answer, but seeing how I don't have 50 reputation (I've been a lurker for years, finally decided to participate) do I really need to ask a few questions before I can comment/answer other people's stuff? Or am I missing something here?

Sorry if this has been answered before, but with a few search tries I couldn't find any similar stuff, even tried google just for "50 reputation stackoverflow" but that didn't give me anything either.

Comment: Welcome to SO as an active user, but this is not really a good start ...  According to [this help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) you can immediately start contributing answers, even with 1 rep.  So, just start answering away :-)  Good luck!

Comment: Then I must have misunderstood something. Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: No, you did not Google. [Proof](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sbg74.png).

Answer (score 2):

I'd refer you to the appropriate help pages

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

With 1 reputation you can **Ask a question or contribute an answer**

which is a core of SO, all other privileges are just add-ons, which needs filtering out "not really participating" members.